# protractor + cucumber - element not visible even though element is visible

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, cucumber

```js
 this.When(/^the user clicks on login button$/, function () {
        return browser.wait(wagLoginPage.loginPage.signIn.isPresent().then(function (visible) {            
            if(visible){
                console.log("element is visible !!!!!!!");
                wagLoginPage.loginPage.signIn.click().then(function(){
                     expect(visible).to.be.true;
                });
            }
            else{
                expect(visible).to.be.true;
            }           
        }, function () { chai.assert.isFalse(true, "SingIn is not visible!") }));
    });
```

[image: Protractor - element is not visible issue]

My test randomly fails in the above step. For the above code, in console window protractor prints 'element is visible'. But if I perform click event on the element it throws element is not visible exception.

**Update**

Questions is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336247/protractor-cucumber-if-assertion-fails-test-execution-stops-abruptly/43353264#43353264)

Comment: Hello! Please post your code in the question instead of a link. Image links go bad, and some networks (like mine) block them. Thankfully I have a cell phone I could view this on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is present, but it's probably not visible.

Try this:

```
return browser.wait(wagLoginPage.loginPage.signIn.isDisplayed().then(function (visible){
    //Your stuff
}
```

Note, I'm using **isDisplayed()** vs. **isPresent()**.

**isPresent()** is useful if you are checking if an element is on the page, but may or may not be visible.

**isDisplayed()** is useful if you are checking if an element is visible on the page.

Comment: After using isDisplayed() it clicks the button only if it is visible. But if button is not visible assertions fails in the else part and stops the test execution abruptly with the below error [15:41:58] E/launcher - expected false to be true
[15:41:58] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected false to be true.[15:41:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Comment: is there a relation between this question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336247/protractor-cucumber-if-assertion-fails-test-execution-stops-abruptly) question?

Comment: @wswebcreation looks to me like it's a similar project, but a different question

Comment: @mrfreester, looks from the same person and almost the same code

Comment: Found complete solution for this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43353264/5538141)