# Protractor + cucumber - if assertion fails test execution stops abruptly

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber

- Cucumber Test Scenario

```js
@login
Scenario: Test signin link
Given the user goes to "example.com"
When the user clicks on login button
Then the current page is the login page
```

Hi, Whenever chai/'Chai as promise' assertion fails my test execution stops abruptly, instead of making the corresponding cucumber step fail. If a scenario has 5 cucumber DSL step and if assertion fails in 2nd step test execution I expect test result should be

- 1 scenario (1 failed)
- 5 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 1 passed)

But I get test result like below with error code 199

- Step Definition

  ```js
  this.When(/^the user clicks on login button$/, function() {
          browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
          return browser.wait(wagHomePage.elements.signIn.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
              if (visible) {
                  wagHomePage.elements.signIn.click().then(function() {
                      expect(visible).to.be.true;
                  });
              }
              else {
                  chai.assert.isTrue(false);
              }
          }));
      });

      this.Then(/^the current page is the login page$/, function() {         
          expect(wagLoginPage.elements.pageIdentifier.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
      });
  ```

```js
@login
  Scenario: Test signin link
  √ Given the user goes to "example.com"
[19:58:02] E/launcher - expected false to be true
[19:58:02] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected false to be true
    at doAsserterAsyncAndAddThen (C:\JS_UIAutomation\node
_modules\chai-as-promised\lib\chai-as-promised.js:293:29)
    at .<anonymous> (C:\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\chai
-as-promised\lib\chai-as-promised.js:283:21)
    at get (C:\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\chai\lib\chai
\utils\overwriteProperty.js:50:37)
    at Function.assert.isTrue (C:\JS_UIAutomation\node_mo
dules\chai\lib\chai\interface\assert.js:332:31)
    at C:\JS_UIAutomation\example_site_tests\step_defin
itions\wagLogin_definition.js:23:29
    at elementArrayFinder_.then (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.ts:840:
22)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\
selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-web
driver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium
-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib
\promise.js:2813:27)
[19:58:02] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Please help me to get proper test result like

- 1 scenario (1 failed)
- 5 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 1 passed)

Comment: I don't get this piece of code `return browser.wait(wagHomePage.elements.signIn.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
            if (visible) {
                wagHomePage.elements.signIn.click().then(function() {
                    expect(visible).to.be.true;
                });
            }
            else {
                chai.assert.isTrue(false);
            }
        }));`
You are first waiting for the element to be displayed, if it is visible, you are clicking on something (that resolves in a promise) and then use the previous result in an expect. Can you explain this?

Comment: Sometimes click action is not performing even-though element is visible. so   to make sure the click action is performed i added a promise expect(visible).to.be.true; but i can remove that. Irrespective of this line i face this issue. Please help

Comment: What is the exact line of code that fails, in the log it says `C:\JS_UIAutomation\example_site_tests\step_definitions\wagLogin_definition.js:23:29`. Can you add a string to your expect like this `expect(visible).to.equal(true, 'Descriptive message: ');`

Comment: It is failing in the else part Chai.assert (which is wagLo‌​gin_definition.js:23‌​:29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem, it looks like you are not implementing the [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) in a correct way. According to the docs it should consist out of a:

1. *condition*: The condition to wait on, defined as a promise, condition object, or a function to evaluate as a condition.
2. *opt_timeout*: How long to wait for the condition to be true.

Your code is this

```
return browser.wait(wagHomePage.elements.signIn.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
    if (visible) {
        wagHomePage.elements.signIn.click().then(function() {
            expect(visible).to.be.true;
        });
    }
    else {
        chai.assert.isTrue(false);
    }
}));
```

It should be more like this

```
// Wait 3 seconds for the element to appear and click on it
// If not the wait wail fail by rejecting the promise with the custom message
return browser.wait(function(){
    return wagHomePage.elements.signIn.isDisplayed()
    .then(function(visible){
        if (visible) {
           // click on the element
           wagHomePage.elements.signIn.click(); 
           return true;
        }
        // Not visible yet, but it is in the DOM, then try again
        return false;
    }).catch(function(notFound){
        // Element not found in the DOM, try again
        return false;
    });   
}, 3000, 'Element not found within 3 seconds');
```

Keep in mind that `isPresent()` checks if the element is present in the DOM, `isDisplayed()` checks if the element is present in the DOM AND visible. If you do a check on `isDisplayed()` you need to do the `catch()`;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much :). This resolved my issue. Now if the element is not visible it throws error message 'Element not found within 3 seconds' and makes corresponding DSL step to fail and move on to execute next test case.Test execution didn't stop abruptly. Thanks !!! :)

Comment: @ThangakumarD, you are welcome. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333350/protractor-cucumber-element-not-visible-even-though-element-is-visible/43333484?noredirect=1#comment73767697_43333484) also related, and if so, can you link to this answer? Then the circle is round again ;-)

Comment: Yes.Both are related. I copied a link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333350/protractor-cucumber-element-not-visible-even-though-element-is-visible/43333484?noredirect=1#comment73775395_43333484). Is this enough ? or is any other way to link answer?

Comment: @Thangakumar, this is good, I also edited your other post with a link to this answer. Grtz